# Spree Error - Error registering calculator Calculator::PriceBucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

Getting this error locally and in production w/ a clean install. Seed data has been loaded. Rails 3.0.3, ruby 1.87 (development) and ruby 1.8.7 REE in prod.

spree gems
spree (0.30.1)
spree_api (0.30.1)
spree_auth (0.30.1)
spree_core (0.30.1)
spree_dash (0.30.1)
spree_promo (0.30.1)
spree_sample (0.30.1)

Development Error:

```
=> Booting WEBrick => Rails 3.0.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000 
=> Call with -d to detach => Ctrl-C to shutdown server 
Error registering calculator Calculator::PriceBucket
[2010-11-27 12:57:49] INFO WEBrick 1.3.1 
[2010-11-27 12:57:49] INFO ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16) [i686-darwin10.4.3] 
[2010-11-27 12:57:49] INFO WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=18146 port=3000
```

Prod Error:

```
Error message:
superclass mismatch for class PriceBucket
Exception class:
TypeError
Application root:
/home/deploy/webstores/mystore/current Backtrace:
```

File Line Location

```
0 /home/deploy/.bundler/ruby/1.8/spree-e9c3485bf22e/core/app/models/calculator/price_bucket.rb 1
```

Comment: this isn't a solution that i'm comfortable with but it works until the spree_core gem is updated 

I forked and "hacked" a fix in to make it work - github.com/dblsystems/spree

Not comfortable with this solution but it works for now.

Comment: Yikes I did that in Rails2 Spree, and I'm trying to avoid that at all costs right now.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me though its a lot different from your error :

It should also be noted that the way things are calculated in Rails3 Spree is a slight bit different. The object now contains the attributes of `item_total`, rather than just calling `object.length`.

In my main extension gem :

```
  def self.activate
    Dir.glob(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "../app/**/*_decorator*.rb")) do |c|
      Rails.env.production? ? require(c) : load(c)
    end
    Calculator::PerWeight.register
  end
```

In my custom calculator:

```
def self.register
  super
  ShippingMethod.register_calculator(self)
end
```